# Parallel Read Write to C++ stringstream

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using std::stringstream for reading/writing binary data.

```
std::stringstream strm(std::stringstream::binary|std::stringstream::in|std::stringstream::out);

    strm.write(...) //happens in one thread
    strm.read(...)  //happens in another thread
```

Does C++ standards guarantees that parallel read write to stringstream work? Or not.

Comment: Does the source for `std::stringstream` have a mutex or atomic in it?

Comment: I am not interested in a particular implementation of `std::stringstream`. I am interested in the specifications of standards.

Comment: If a "standards compliant" stdc++ library does not have mutexes or other mechanism for thread safety, then its a high probability that its not required by the standard.

Comment: The C++ standard makes no claims whatsoever as to the thread-safety of `std::stringstream`. Such safety, if provided, is left to the implementation, and is *not* guaranteed by the standard. In fact, prior to C++11, there was no acknowledgement in the C++ standard as to the existence of threads *at all*, much less harboring safety while performing operations therein.  But don't take my word for it; get a copy of the standard and hunt it down.

Comment: @WhozCraig -- Agree. Just wanted to understand post C++11 scenario.

Comment: The general case of IO streams covers it in brevity: C++11 § 27.2.3 (iostreams.threadsafety) states: "1. Concurrent access to a stream object, stream buffer object, or C Library stream by multiple threads may result in a data race unless otherwise specified. Note: Data races result in undefined behavior. — end note. 2. If one thread makes a library call a that writes a value to a stream and, as a result, another thread reads this value from the stream through a library call b such that this does not result in a data race, then a’s write synchronizes with b’s read.

Comment: a quick websearch http://www.google.com/#q=stringstream+concurrent leads to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/4--LgXQy8q0 and they basically say that is implementation dependant behaviour, and I'm not surprised by that, `stringstream` it's part of the C++ standard library and so it's not part of the "core" language, and often times the C++ specifications leave a significant degree of freedom to the actual implementation of the standard library itself.

Answer (score 1):

My fstream.h file at /usr/local/pgi/linux86-64/13.10/include/CC/fstream.h contains no mention of mutex locks. Further, in programs I have written output using << operator to stringstream files can become interleaved if written at the 'same' time.

Since you're reading from and writing to the same file, I imagine the line order is important?
As such, I think you want a global mutex lock between threads.

Something like:

```
#include ....

pthread_mutex_t FileMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

std::stringstream strm(std::stringstream::binary|...)

int main()
{

blah blah

pthread_create(&threads, NULL, function, voidPtrToArguments);

blah blah

}

void *function(void *voidPtrToArguments)
{
blah blah some more

pthread_mutex_lock(&FileMutex);
strm.write(...);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&FileMutex);

}
```

and then the same for a function to read.

Comment: Does C++11 standards says anything specific for parallel behavior or `std::stringstream` ? Particular implementations are important; yet I am more interested in the specifications for `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Are you looking for:
27.2.3 Thread safety [iostreams.threadsafety]

1 Concurrent access to a stream object (27.8, 27.9), stream buﬀer object (27.6), or C Library stream (27.9.2)
by multiple threads may result in a data race (1.10) unless otherwise speciﬁed (27.4). 
[ Note: Data races
result in undeﬁned behavior (1.10). — end note ]

2 If one thread makes a library call a that writes a value to a stream and, as a result, another thread reads
this value from the stream through a library call b such that this does not result in a data race, then a’s
write synchronizes with b’s read.

Comment: Apologies for the way that formatted so poorly - the source is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf page  980

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in [iostreams.threadsafety] in the Standard. The C++17 text reads:

> Concurrent access to a stream object, stream buffer object, or C Library stream by
>   multiple threads may result in a data race unless otherwise specified. [Note: Data races result in undefined behavior . —end note ]

There is no "otherwise specified" for `std::stringstream` so your case would be undefined behaviour.